# Why does printing input buffer result in unexpected output?

Tags: c

In the following code, whenever the same string is input in arrays "pass" and "repass", the string in "repass" gets doubled. For example, if the input string in "pass" and "repass" are aaaaaaaa then the string in "repass" becomes aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa because of which `strcmp()` gives a negative answer.

Can somebody help and explain the reason behind this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()  
{  
    char user_name[20],pass[8],repass[8];  
    int i=0,c=0,tr=1;//tr for no of try(should less than 3 )  
    clrscr();  
    puts("enter user name");  
    gets(user_name);  
    printf("\n\n\n\n");  

    for(tr=1;tr<=3;tr++)  
    {  
        puts("\n\nenter password");  

        while(i<8)  
        {  
            pass[i] = getch();  
            putchar('*');  
            i++;  
        }  

        printf("\n\n\n\nplease reenter the password\n\n");  
        i=0;  

        while(i<8)  
        {  
            repass[i]=getch();  
            putchar('*');  
            i++;  
        }  

        c=strcmp(pass, repass);  
        printf("c=%d", c);  

        if(strcmp(pass,repass)==0)  
            c=0;  
        else  
            c++;  

        if(c==0)  
        {  
            printf("\n\n\t****\vsuccessful login*********** ");  
            break;  
        }  
        else  
            printf("\n\nsorry password did not match");  
    }  

    if(tr>3)  
        puts("\n\nlogin failed");  
    //printf("%s        %s",pass,repass);  
    getch();  
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code; recommendation for SO is 4 spaces per level, no tabs.

Comment: Also, don't they teach not to use `gets`???

Answer (score 2):

You're not 0-terminating your strings so using "string" functions on them (printing with "%s", strcmp, etc) is illegal.

In this particular case it looks as `repass` is "doubled" because of the stack layout, the way `pass` and `repass` are one next to the other.

---

Side node, use [`fgets` instead of `gets`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/getsvsfgets.html).

Comment: +1.  What's actually happening is that, since `pass` has no null-terminator, the two stack variables `pass` and `repass` end up forming part of a single contiguous string.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Yup, that's exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things wrong here.

1. Don't use gets.  Gets is insecure.  Get out of the habit of using it.  Use scanf instead.
2. You're not null-terminating your strings.  Strings require a `'\0'` at the end to signal that they're done.
3. Please format your code better.  It will help you follow the logic if you do.